# How to bypass the problem of qt version missing for 64bit android?

Tags: android, qt, build, architecture, toolchain

I installed Qt 5.11.2(http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.11/5.11.2/qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.11.2.exe) to build an Android app. Qt creator auto-detects 3 Qt versions:
Qt 5.11.2  for Android ARMv7,
Qt 5.11.2  for Android x86,
Qt 5.11.2  MinGW 32bit. 
I think they are all 32 bit.

But when I created a project, in the "select Kits" step, it says "Android has not been configured. Create Android kits.". When I clicked the "configure" button, in Device/Android, it says "Cannot create kits for all architectures. Qt versions are missing for the following architectures: arm-linux-android-elf-64bit, x86-linux-android-elf-64bit. To add the Qt version,select Options > Build&Run > Qt Versions". But I do not want to build the 64 bit app. I just want to build the 32bit app using the existing Qt versions. How to bypass this error and build a 32bit Android app? I wonder why it refers to the 64 bit architectures, just because the 32 bit qt is installed on 64 bit machine?